# Why am I getting this error "The current type,..., is an interface and cannot be constructed. Are you missing a type mapping?"

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection, prism

I'm using Prism 6.3, Unity Container 4, WPF. The error I'm getting is "current type ... is an Interface and cannot be constructed..." when I try to resolve a class but it seems to me that I have mapped everything correctly. I've used this before and had no problem...am baffled.

I have a module that contains an interface called ICurrentWorkingEmail that maps to a class of CurrentWorkingModel. I created the module class (IModule) BizCoreModule, where these types are registered with the container.

```
public class BizCoreModule : IModule
{
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    public BizCoreModule(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }
    public void Initialize()
    {
        _container.RegisterType<ICurrentWorkingEmail, CurrentWorkingEmail>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());
    }

}
```

In the bootstrapper I have registered the module with the Module Catalog. Note there seems to be different ways to do this, and have tried them, but seems to make no difference...I stuck with what I've used in the past.

```
protected override IModuleCatalog CreateModuleCatalog()
{
    ModuleCatalog catalog = new ModuleCatalog();
    catalog.AddModule(typeof(DataLayerModule));
    catalog.AddModule(typeof(BizCoreModule));
    return catalog;
}
```

When debugging I've been injecting the container into a view model and trying to resolve the CurrentWorkingEmail class in the contructor (wouldn't normally do that).

```
    private IUnityContainer _container;
    public SearchViewModel(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
        var currentWorkingEmail = _container.Resolve<ICurrentWorkingEmail>();
    }
```

The error occurs on the _container.Resolve()

Comment: When debugging, if you put a breakpoint at `BizCoreModule.Initialize`, do you reach it before `SearchViewModel.SearchViewModel`? Also, is the container instance the same?

Comment: Thanks Haukinger, I did what you suggested and realized I was trying to resolve it before it was actually registered. I was trying to resolve it in the MainWindow but apparently the MainWindow loads before the module catalogs are registered. So the solution was to move those components into modules, which was what I probably should have done anyway. Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Haukinger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5758420/haukinger) pointed me to the problem. I was trying to resolve ICurrentWorkingEmail before the catalog was initiated. I didn't realize that the shell will load before the catalogs are initiated...and I was trying to use the CurrentWorkingEmail in the shell's viewmodel. To fix this I moved the shell component into it's own module and injected it using the region manager.